# Reemplazar un dato concreto en lectura de archivo csv con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bash

estoy intentando reemplazar datos concretos de un dataframe de una columa pero de distintas filas con un bucle. Pero a la hora de sustituir el "Connected" o "Disconnected" de una fila en concreto, no se realiza el cambio, he visto que el .iat si funciona cuando creas el dataframe, pero a la hora de leer el dataframe no funciona .iat . La idea es hacer un ping a todas las IP almacenadas en una columna del dataframe, esto es lo que tengo:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

locali= "./"
locali2= "NETSYS/Dispositivos/dispositives_list/"
archivo="sergio2"

global dfdisp
dfdisp = pd.read_csv(locali+locali2+archivo+".csv",sep=";")


global contador
contador=0

with open('hola.csv','r') as reader:

    for x in reader.readlines():

        response=os.system("ping -c 3 " + x + ">/dev/null 2>&1")

        if response == 0:
            ping="Connected"
        else:
            ping="Disconnected"

        dfdisp.iat[contador,4]=ping
        contador+=1
```

En el bucle lee cada dirección IP del archio "hola.csv", las direcciones IP del archivo están en el mismo orden que las IPs del dataframe, se hace un ping a dicha IP, si hay conexión con la IP, la variable ping almacenará "Connected" y este tendrá que almacenarse en en la columna "PING" del dataframe.

Con "dfdisp.iat[contador,4]=ping" estoy intentado sustituir el valor de la fila 0 y de la columna 4, el número de fila se irá cambiando con "contador+=1.

Este es el dataframe:

```
     ALIAS HOSTNAME       IP   SYST          PING     USER PASSWORD
0  router1      ISP  1.1.1.1  cisco  Disconnected  sergio1  sergio1
1  router2     ISP2  8.8.8.8  cisco  Disconnected  sergio2  sergio2
```

Otro problema es que en la terminal se visualiza el resultado de ping incluso añadiendo ">/dev/null 2>&1" en el comando ping. Pienso que es problema de la variable x, debido a que en otro script con el mismo comando ping pero sustituyendo la variable x por otra que contenga una ip, no se visualiza lo que hace ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay ningún problema con usar `iat` tal como lo haces, pero ten en cuenta que ésto modifica el dataframe no el csv.

En cuanto a lo de que en la terminal se visualiza el resultado de `ping`, no uses `os.system` es una API en la práctica obsoleta, usa `subprocess`, para tu caso `subprocess.run` con `capture_output=True` para redirigir la salida basta:

Algunas otras observaciones:

- No es recomendable construir rutas concatenando cadenas, usa os.path.join o pathlib directamente.
- No uses `readlines` si no necesitas todas las lineas de un archivo en memoria simultáneamente, itera sobre el fichero directamente.

---

```
import pathlib
import subprocess

import pandas as pd


locali = "./"
locali2 = "NETSYS/Dispositivos/dispositives_list/"
archivo = "sergio2"

file_path = pathlib.Path(locali, locali2, f"{archivo}.csv")

dfdisp = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=";")

with open('hola.csv', 'r') as reader:
    for contador, line in enumerate(reader):
        ip = line.rstrip()
        response = subprocess.run(
            ["ping", "-c", "3", ip],
            capture_output=True
            ).returncode
        ping = "Connected" if response == 0 else "Disconnected"
        dfdisp.iat[contador, 4] = ping
        
dfdisp.to_csv(file_path, sep=";", index=False)
```

---

### Archivos de prueba

**`./NETSYS/Dispositivos/dispositives_list/sergio2.csv`**

> ALIAS;HOSTNAME;IP;SYST;PING;USER;PASSWORD
> router1;ISP;1.1.1.1;cisco;Disconnected;sergio1;sergio1
> router2;ISP2;8.8.8.8;cisco;Disconnected;sergio2;sergio2

**`./hola.csv`**

> 1.1.1.1
> 8.8.8.8

La salida, si se tiene conexión a internet y los servidores DNS no pasan de ti... :)

**`./NETSYS/Dispositivos/dispositives_list/sergio2.csv`**

> ALIAS;HOSTNAME;IP;SYST;PING;USER;PASSWORD
> router1;ISP;1.1.1.1;cisco;Connected;sergio1;sergio1
> router2;ISP2;8.8.8.8;cisco;Connected;sergio2;sergio2

Comment: Me aparece un error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1